# How to build an AWS serverless Apollo Federation API which is constructed from subgraphs in separate microservices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, apollo-federation

**The Task:**
Imagine a large-ish company or product that has many microservices run by separate teams. Each microservice exists in a separate repo. You want to build a single unified Apollo GraphQL API which collates all the subgraphs from the separate microservice APIs. And you want to build it using Serverless technologies. The Unified API should be authenticated using Cognito but the underlying subgraph APIs shouldn't be exposed to the public internet.

**Ideal Scenario:** AWS-AppSync would support federation natively.

**In reality Scenario:** Since this can't be done easily we have to run the Apollo Federation Server in a lambda which is fronted by API Gateway. The setup of the Federation server knows where the endpoints are for the subgraph.

**Question:** How to we construct the subgraphs using AppSync or further Lambda servers for each microservice, or something else? What techniques have people used to deploy Apollo Federation within AWS?

**Design Considerations:**

*Resources Based Policies:*
What I would prefer is the API-Gateway to be authenticated with Cognito but the App Sycn subgraphs to be given full access to the Lambda. However because App Sync doesn't support Resource Based Policies this isn't possible.

*API-Key:*
I can use API-Key auth on the subgraphs but since AppSync has publically accessible endpoints this feels like a security risk.

*Cognito:*
A possibility - would need to pass through Cognito auth from API-Gateway, to Lambda, then to subgraphs. Feels icky.

*Lambda Authorization:*
Add Lambda auth for subgraphs and use request context(?) to determine the request was coming internally. A hack for resource-based policies.

*Out to Internet and Back Subgraph:*
AppSync provides a pubilc url for the endpoint and composing the federated graph pulls the schemas to build the supegraph schema. This feels like internal services going out to the internet and then back in.  The best solution would be some internal ip addresses / urls and hosting all the subgraphs within a private VPC.

Conclusion:
Building a secure federated graph feels hacky with serverless technologies. It feels like I should avoid AppSync all together and use a subgraphs (Private API Gateways in private VPC - powered by Lambdas) feeding info to a Public API Gateway authenticated by Cognito.

Interested in thoughts.